# Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-value-(email), starting an object on a scalar field

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am implementing firebase into my application for the first time. I am receiving this error:

"Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-value-(email),-starting-an-object-on-a-scalar-field-invalid-value-(password),-starting-an-object-on-a-scalar-field)."

My code:

registerscreen.js

```
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

    export default function RegisterScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [name, setName] = useState({ value: '', error: '' })
  const [email, setEmail] = useState({ value: '', error: '' })
  const [password, setPassword] = useState({ value: '', error: '' })


  const handleSignUp =() => {
    const nameError = nameValidator(name.value)
    const emailError = emailValidator(email.value)
    const passwordError = passwordValidator(password.value)
    if (emailError || passwordError || nameError) {
      setName({ ...name, error: nameError })
      setEmail({ ...email, error: emailError })
      setPassword({ ...password, error: passwordError })
      return
    }
    auth
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then(userCredentials => {
        const user = userCredentials.user;
        console.log(user.email)
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error.message))
  }
```

firebase.js

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyA1zo9ci0RXQYBNUooGtSK2b29OPxOC0GE",
  authDomain: "aslassistfinal.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://aslassistfinal-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "aslassistfinal",
  storageBucket: "aslassistfinal.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "380652280816",
  appId: "1:380652280816:web:5f49bf6df4977cdb401b35",
  //measurementId: "G-TYX10C1CBE"
};

// Initialize Firebase

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth(app);

export { auth }
```

I cannot find this error in the documentation [found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors)

I have confirmed that the email and password I am using to authenticate is valid.

Thank you in advance for any help and if you need any other info let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

In my state I had:

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState({ value: '', error: '' })
  const [password, setPassword] = useState({ value: '', error: '' })
```

In my inputfields I had:

```
<TextInput
    label="Email"
    returnKeyType="next"
    value={email.value}
    onChangeText={(text) => setEmail({ value: text, error: '' })}
    error={!!email.error}
    errorText={email.error}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCompleteType="email"
    textContentType="emailAddress"
    keyboardType="email-address"
  />
  <TextInput
    label="Password"
    returnKeyType="done"
    value={password.value}
    onChangeText={(text) => setPassword({ value: text, error: '' })}
    error={!!password.error}
    errorText={password.error}
    secureTextEntry
  />
```

I am still unsure what the exact meaning of the error is but I changed my state to:

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
```

And my input fields to:

```
  <TextInput
    label="Email"
    returnKeyType="next"
    value={email.value}
    onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
    error={!!email.error}
    errorText={email.error}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCompleteType="email"
    textContentType="emailAddress"
    keyboardType="email-address"
  />
  <TextInput
    label="Password"
    returnKeyType="done"
    value={password.value}
    onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
    error={!!password.error}
    errorText={password.error}
    secureTextEntry
  />
```

And now I am having no problems. Although I wanted to set error's in my state management, I will just work around it and do something else.

Comment: I also want to add that stopping and restarting also helped as well.

Comment: The error means that a field (email or password in this case) is invalid. Please check the network request and there in the payload you will see the exact body that is being sent in the request. You are probably sending an object or something instead of a string

Comment: @Corey, Use the solution below, you don't need to change your code implementation because of the error.

Answer (score 3):

You were getting this error because 'email' was initialized as an **object** here which comprised of **value** & **error** as 2 strings - *const [email, setEmail] = useState({ **value: '', error: ''** })*

Firebase auth is expecting string values in *createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)* method so you need to use ***email.value*** instead of just ***email*** & same goes for password as well.

ANOTHER TIP - you might also want to remove your firebase credentials from here (firebase.js) as they might get misused

Comment: Great one, been stack for a few hours here! cheers